# Microsoft Access automatically rounds numbers

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

Under a column that has a number data type. I am trying to enter the number 11.50, but the system is automatically changing it to 12.00.

Answer (score 1):

because this type `numbers` can handle only numbers with out any fractions

you must change this datatype to be `double`

Answer (score 1):

There are two settings for Number fields Field Size and Decimal Places. At first, you should change Field Size from Integer to either single, double.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the table open in design mode, click on the field in question. In the lower pane you will see properties of the number, change the field size to either Single or Double.